# Not able to setTextto the EditView in the TextWatcher

Tags: java, android, textview, textwatcher

I have a EditView called "text".
I have implemented textWatcher

```
   text.addTextChangedListener(this);
```

Whenever i try to set EditView to some value in the TextWatcher,it is throwing Force close.

Here's the code:

```
 public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) 
 {

  }
 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int end)
  {
//text.setText("");
    }
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
{       
     //text.setText("");
}
```

My requirement is : Whenever the user type some value,the EditView has to set back to Null.
Please help me out.

Comment: Well what's wrong with those comments over there? You may want to implement a `focusLost` listener.

Comment: show your logcat.and put all your code if possible

Comment: is it a TextView or an EditText View? Where will the user enter values?

Comment: i think your are using EditText instead of Textview..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {
}

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int end) {
}

public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){       
    s.clear();
}
```